# Grub Menu not showing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, 19.04, reboot

I have a dual boot laptop(Fujitsu Lifebook T725) with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz. When I start it, it directly boots up Ubuntu and skips the Grub menu. This is my grub file in /etc/default.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Can someone please help me? I even tried pressing the shift and esc keys when it loads, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out like

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=
```

Then run: `sudo update-grub`.
It's been a while, but I believe I remember some conflict between GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT & GRUB_TIMEOUT. Perhaps no value isn't enough.

Comment: I had tried that too. When I start my computer, it displays an empty screen for sometime and then boots up Ubuntu. I even tried adding 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu'. When I enter 'sudo update-grub' it does say '''Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done'''
and then I reboot, but the menu doesn't show up.

Comment: So you are booting UEFI ...   
it is possible your BIOS needs to switch the primary boot device and that it is defaulting. Some time ago I wound up staying on legacy BIOS because of something of this nature.

Comment: Any idea of how I could do that? I am kinda new to all this.

Comment: You'd have to go into your system BIOS, and work through nominating boot order of devices. If this is unfamiliar to you, your best bet is likely youtube videos.

Comment: Alright, will do! Thanks, Mark!